# Django Python if block on template file (string)

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to ad a condition into an html model in Django (python) and it is not working:

This is my HTML:

```
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6">{{ post.author }} </p>
                    {% if post.author  == 'John_Woo' %}
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6"> NOK </p>
                    {% else %}
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6"> ok </p>
                    {% endif %}
```

Not sure what is wrong here...
Even though I have a **John_Woo** author, I only get **ok** message

This is my models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
```

This is my views.py:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post

class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'

class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
```

Comment: Can you show the code to your views.py and models.py files?

Comment: Almost certainly, `author` is a ForeignKey, so it will never equal a string. But show your model.

Comment: Edited with views.py and models.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Post.author` returns class's representation like(**str**, **unicode**, **repr**) function. You have to override this functions which is depends on your django version. But you have one way to compare this. Like `if Post.author.first_name == "John_Woo"`

Answer (score 1):

You want `post.author.name` (where `.name` is whatever field of an `User` object that will sometimes contain the string `'John_Woo'` )